# Send a link to whatsapp group directly from browser (or from app)

Tags: android, ios, iphone, url-scheme, whatsapp

I want to enable users to share a URL+ text with a WhatsApp group. I want this to work both from iPhones and Androids. However my app is in a browser (it's a website). I'm currently looking into 2 options, but both have issues:

**1) The first potential solution - sharing directly from the browser.**

I checked out [WhatsApp's URL schema](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013) and used the following URL to share through my app:

```
"whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!"
```

However there were several problems with this approach:

- It seems to work only with iPhones and not with Androids. Is there a comparable solution somewhere for Androids?
- It enables to choose who to send to only after you are redirected to WhatsApp, unless you know the address book ID (=`abid`) of the user. First, I do not know how to access the abid of users? Second, I am trying to send to a group, in which case there is no abid (right?), and therefore it seems impossible to do this. Is that true?
  Also, what happens for Android apps? What is the comparable to the abid, for a group, and how do I get it?

**2) The second potential solution - creating a native app which is identical with the browser-based app, but this specific part (where we do the "sharing") is native.**

However, it seems to me that in this case I have very similar problems to the ones described above:

- I can see how to do this for iOS on WhatsApp's website (see the link above). However, does the WhatsApp URL schema work with Android native apps as well?
- Again, the address book ID issue is the same. How do I get it? It may be easier to get the abid on iOS given that we are now a native app, but does it exist for a group? And how about the Android app? Would this share to WhatsApp group work there?

Comment: As for your question "Is there a comparable solution somewhere for Androids?" : there are many ways in Android to allow interaction with other apps (look up Intent Filters) - if the WhatsApp Android app does have a URL scheme declared in its manifest then it will work, otherwise it will not.

Comment: On WhatsApp's site I only saw a reference to a url schema for iPhones. Where can I find out?

Comment: I don't know, I've never used WhatsApp, but if they provide a way, it should be in the documentation. A previous poster seems to have succeeded here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768688/sending-message-through-whatsapp-by-intent

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that; though I'm not sure he's sending to a group

Comment: look this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786145/whatsapp-link-on-products/22845002#22845002

Comment: Hi Lucy, have you found a way to send to a group, I am also wondering about this?

Answer (score 8):

Sharing directly from the browser works both in iPhone and Android if you use WhatsApp version 2.11 or higher. As you said it DIDN'T USED TO work in Android.

U can use the same URL

```
"whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!"
```

Knowing abid is not possible as far as I know.

Hope this was helpful.

Thank You.

Comment: this is works for android and whatsApp 2.12.5 for me, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

in Android you can invite friends from an app using Intent, see the following Code

```
final ComponentName name = new ComponentName("com.whatsapp", "com.whatsapp.ContactPicker");
Intent oShareIntent = new Intent();
oShareIntent.setComponent(name);
oShareIntent.setType("text/plain");
oShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Your Message");
startActivity(oShareIntent);
```

I hope this solves your problem

Comment: Thank you, this looks like the right direction. However this only includes sending to contacts, right? I want to be able to send to a group, how can I do that?

Comment: hi sir do u know  how to WhatsApp group link share WhatsApp application objective c?