# In android, how to share content directly to particular whatsapp group or user?

Tags: android, whatsapp, android-sharing

I have a name of group or user to which I want to share. How is it possible to auto select a user by it's name while sharing it to WhatsApp using intent.

Please check below image. Contact is automatically filtered and selected by name. You can check the functionality by trying Siftr Magic app.

Link:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.siftr.whatsappcleaner&hl=en

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567538/send-a-link-to-whatsapp-group-directly-from-browser-or-from-app

Comment: The link you shared above is not what I want. It is going to open out whatsapp conversation having list of Frequently contacted as well as Recent chats. I want user or group with the particular name is selected automatically. Please check attched image.